# "Settings Updated" message Stopped showing

Tags: php, wordpress

I was using the code below as a Plugin to create a "Options Menu Page" for wordpress:

```
add_action('admin_init', 'cardin_options_init' );
add_action('admin_menu', 'cardin_options_add_page');

function cardin_options_init(){
    register_setting( 'cardin_options_options', 'cardin_options');
}

function cardin_options_add_page() {
    add_options_page('Cardin Options', 'Cardin Options', 'manage_options', 'cardin_options', 'cardin_options_do_page');
}

function cardin_options_do_page() {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div id="icon-options-general" class="icon32"><br></div>
        <h2>Cardin Options</h2>
        <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php settings_fields('cardin_options_options'); ?>
            <?php $options = get_option('cardin_options'); ?>
            <table class="form-table">
                <tr valign="top"><th scope="row">Information</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="cardin_options[information]" value="<?php echo $options['information']; ?>" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" class="button-primary" name="submit" value="<?php _e('Save Changes') ?>" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php   
}
```

It's working how it should, but, later I decided to create my Own Plugin Menu Page, not a 'Settings' sub-menu, then, I changed the line below:

```
add_options_page('Cardin Options', 'Cardin Options', 'manage_options', 'cardin_options', 'cardin_options_do_page');
```

to:

```
add_menu_page('Cardin Options', 'Cardin Options', 'manage_options', 'cardin_options', 'cardin_options_do_page');
```

It worked, but when i click "Save Changes" the "Settings Updated" message doesn't display anymore. What should I do to make it display again?

Thanks alot in advance and sorry for the bad english.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if($_POST['oscimp_hidden'] == 'Y') {   ?>
<div id="message" class="updated">
    <p><strong><?php _e('Settings saved.') ?></strong></p>
</div>
```

edit:
heres a guide: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/creating-a-custom-wordpress-plugin-from-scratch/
search for: `if($_POST['oscimp_hidden'] == 'Y') {`

Comment: Hey, Thanks for answering me, so kind of you, however, I still didn't figure out how to make it work. Thanks again.